# How do you texture a remeshed particle system?

Tags: texturing, uv, particles, shaders, vector-mapping

I try to make some interactive soil! And I already set something up that kind of works, but I have some problems in texturing it!

What I did by now is... I made a particle simulation via the molecular script, applied a particle instance modifier to another object and put a remesh modifier on top of it, plus two displacement modifiers and one subsurface modifier! So, but now I have the problem that I cannot texture it properly with image textures!

Does anyone have a solution for this?

[image: I already tried to map a texture via the object location, but as you see, this does not work!]